# GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected?

Tags: chromium, gnome-shell-extensions, ubuntu-20.04

I have followed these steps while installing the gnome extension of chromium in Ubuntu 20.04.

1. Installed the GNOME Shell integration extension on chromium.
2. As per their documentation ran a command to install chrome-gnome-shell

   sudo apt-get install chrome-gnome-shell

Still while loading the gnome-extensions page, it is showing error that "Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected. Refer documentation for instructions about installing connector."

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue in steps?

Answer (score 20):

FYI: starting from Ubuntu 21.10 Firefox comes as a default browser and as a snap, as well as Chromium. And has [the same problem](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1741074): GNOME Shell integration shows the same error.
Other ways to install the extensions are:

1. `gnome-extensions install --force your_downloaded_extension.zip`
2. `unzip your_downloaded_extension.zip ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/`

Answer (score 15):

Probably this is because you are running Chromium as a Snap. There is an open bug in Launchpad about this, that appears to still be happening in Ubuntu 20.04 (still happening in Ubuntu 22.04):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1741074

The easiest solution would probably be to use another web browser, not in a Snap.

Comment: Okay. I have installed the same on firefox and problem isn't there but except for firefox the broweser which i have used chrome, chrommium, opera. in all of these I am facing the same problem.

Comment: With the default firefox from ubuntu 20.04 it's working

Answer (score 6):

I experienced this issue when upgrading from Ubuntu 21.04 to Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish), where Firefox was installed via snap - supposedly the sandboxing made it unable to detect.

My resolution (which brought back gnome extensions connector being seen) was to install firefox manually by debian package via the directions in https://balintreczey.hu/blog/firefox-on-ubuntu-22-04-from-deb-not-from-snap/ . You may also be able to install the direct tarball following directions in https://fostips.com/install-latest-firefox-non-esr-debian/

Another option is to use a native extension manager as suggested in https://haydenjames.io/ubuntu-22-04-install-gnome-extensions-manager-workaround/

Comment: The native extension manager you link to at the end of your answer is super easy to use. I don't understand why this isn't the default way to install and manage Gnome extensions. With Ubuntu 22.04 Firefox and Chromium are snaps and using a browser to manage Gnome extensions has become a big hassle.

Comment: I will second that the extension manager is the way to go! way better than messing around with flakey browser extensions.

Answer (score 5):

If you still got problems, you could simply do this:

```
sudo apt-get reinstall chrome-gnome-shell
```

Comment: thank you. your suggestion saved my life. In linux world, reinstalling is considered as a sin to solve any problem. But this is life saver.

Answer (score 3):

For me it did work after all, but just by using another browser - Firefox

Answer (score 3):

I solved using Chrome and not more Firefox for extensions.gnome.

(I use Chrome just for manage this extension)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `Ubuntu 20.10` and I also had this issue. I was using Chromium but I found that Chromium dropped support for this, therefore I installed Firefox from the software. This did not work either.

The fix was to uninstall Firefox from `software` and install Firefox from `ubuntu software` with the source: `ubuntu-groovy-updates-main`

I installed the browser extension on there and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

*Aevin J* He gave the answer if you're on ubuntu 21.10. it really matters whom you install it from. don't use the default one, use the one with most reviews